# What does it mean when the output of $ls -lasrt includes '.' and '..'

Tags: directory, ls

I input the command:

```
     $ ls -lasrt
```

And the output includes (there are more results, these are the ones that confuse me):

```
   4 drwxr-xr-x 5 tuc40953 stdchem  4096 Jul  3 17:48 ..
   4 drwxr-xr-x 2 tuc40953 stdchem  4096 Jul  5 10:03 .
```

Could this mean that the last things that were written are in the previous directory?

Comment: Your directory is empty

Comment: @Bernhard  I forgot to mention, there was MUCH MORE output than this alone.  I just wanted to find what these specific lines meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every directory has a reference to itself, named `.`.  That's a hard link, it actually exists as an entry in the directory itself. Every directory has a reference (again, a hard link) to its parent directory, named `..`

What you see is the contents of a directory with no files or subdirectories in it. Since the date on `.` is July 5, and the date on `..` is July 3, something happened in `.` after it was created, after something happened in `..`  By "something happened", I mean file or directory creation or deletion.

Comment: You can use `-A` instead of `-a` to avoid having them printed.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the files sorted by date including hidden files , given the size of blocks of each file.

Comment: True, but I think the part he was interested in is why there's `.` and `..`